# Splitting field of $x^3 - 3x + 1 \in \mathbb Q[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, proof-verification

> Determine the splitting field of the polynomial $p(x) = x^3 - 3x + 1 \in \mathbb Q[x]$.

I verified that $p(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q[x]$. Then $(p(x))$ is maximal and $\mathbb Q[x]/(p(x))$ is a field.
Then $[x] = x + (p(x)) \in \mathbb Q[x]/(p(x))$ is a root of $p(x)$.
With the division algorithm we find that
$$p(x) = (x - [x])(x^2+[x]x + [x]^2 - 3) \tag{$\star$}$$
Now, to find the other two we'll use the quadratic formula, which is valid since $2 \neq 0$:
$$x^2 + \alpha x + \beta = 0 \iff x = \frac{-\alpha \pm \sqrt{\alpha^2 - 4\beta}}2$$
Let $\gamma^2 = \alpha^2 - 4\beta\ (\ast)$. The solution will be in $\mathbb Q[x]/(p(x))$ iff $\gamma \in \mathbb Q[x]/(p(x))$, or $\gamma = ax^2 + bx + c$. From $(\star)$, $\alpha = [x]$ and $\beta = [x]^2 - 3$. Substituting into $(\ast)$ and using the identity principle between polynomials we find the system
$$\begin{cases}
3a^2 +b^2 +2ac = -3\\
-a^2 + 6ab + 2cb = 0\\
c^2 - 2ab = 12
\end{cases}$$

The solutions are $(-2, -1, 4)$ and $(2, 1, -4)$.

Is the above correct? And can I conclude that $\mathbb Q[x]/(p(x))$ is the splitting field of $p(x)$?

Comment: can you explain better "the solution will be in ${\begin{align} \mathbb{Q} [x] / (p(x)) \end{align} }$ iff ..." ?  ${\begin{align} \\ \end{align} }$ Anyway ${\begin{align} \gamma \notin \mathbb{Q} [x] /(p(x)) \text{ thus the splitting field can't be } \mathbb{Q} [x] /(p(x)) \end{align} }$.

Comment: @TizianoNicolardi That's surprising, because I've chosen $\gamma$ to be in $\mathbb Q[x]/(p(x))$. I meant to say that we want the root of $x^2 + \alpha x + \beta$ in $\mathbb Q[x]/(p(x))$. In order for that to happen, there must be a polynomial in $\mathbb Q[x]/(p(x))$ (which we call $\gamma$) satisfying $\gamma^2 = \alpha^2 - 4\beta$.

Comment: Let $\zeta$ be a primitive 9th root of unity, let $x=\zeta+\zeta^{-1}$, and see what happens.

Comment: @rubik yes, now I understand the sense of that system of equations. So yes, if there's a polynomial ${\gamma}$ of degree two in [x] satisfying ${\gamma^2 = 12 - 3[x]^2}$ then ${\gamma \in \mathbb{Q}[x]/(p(x)) }$. So ${\mathbb{Q}[x]/(p(x))}$ is a splitting field, an extension of degree 3 of ${\mathbb{Q}}$.